# Android app automation with Appium

Tags: android, appium, inspector, uiautomatorviewer

i am using appium and java to automate an android app. I am stuck in a screen which is a custom view. Appium and UI automatorviewer are not able to identify elements in this screen. what should i do now? is there any way to identify elements and perform action ?

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the screen shot of the screen from the UIAutomatior along with UIElements hierarchy?

Comment: @Vinod I have added screenshot. So in above image the red highlighting element is from screen which is present in background. there is no hierarchy for the elements which in on screens.

Comment: I have checked the screen shot by installing on my device as well. Unfortunately, as of now there is no way detect those elements. I have seen such issue in past as well. There could be two solutions: 1. Wait till Google releases the updated version of UIAutomator which can detect this kind of elements OR 2. Ask developers to use different view which can be detected by UIAutomator.

Comment: Hm.. Thanks Bro @Vinod